# IP forwarding over OpenVPN (tun0) with external forwarded ports

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I am trying to configure a very basic routing setup with Ubuntu Server 15.04.

I have an internal interface p4p1 (IP 192.168.0.23) and a working OpenVPN connection using tun0.

I want to forward all traffic from p4p1 through to tun0 and the internet so that my entire network gets the benefits of the OpenVPN connection - nothing new I know.

Obviously this is a common thing and there are guides around the net, I followed this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router. Specifically "4.5. Enable IP forwarding and Masquerading" and it all works as expected - except my externally forwarded ports do not work any more. From that article this is the script I am using:

```
echo -e "\n\nLoading simple rc.firewall-iptables version $FWVER..\n"
DEPMOD=/sbin/depmod
MODPROBE=/sbin/modprobe

EXTIF="tun0"
INTIF="p4p1"

echo "   External Interface:  $EXTIF"
echo "   Internal Interface:  $INTIF"

#======================================================================
#== No editing beyond this line is required for initial MASQ testing == 
echo -en "   loading modules: "
echo "  - Verifying that all kernel modules are ok"
$DEPMOD -a
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -en "ip_tables, "
$MODPROBE ip_tables
echo -en "nf_conntrack, " 
$MODPROBE nf_conntrack
echo -en "nf_conntrack_ftp, " 
$MODPROBE nf_conntrack_ftp
echo -en "nf_conntrack_irc, " 
$MODPROBE nf_conntrack_irc
echo -en "iptable_nat, "
$MODPROBE iptable_nat
echo -en "nf_nat_ftp, "
$MODPROBE nf_nat_ftp
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "   Done loading modules.\n"
echo "   Enabling forwarding.."
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "   Enabling DynamicAddr.."
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr 
echo "   Clearing any existing rules and setting default policy.."

iptables-restore <<-EOF
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o "$EXTIF" -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i "$INTIF" -o "$EXTIF" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
COMMIT
EOF

echo -e "\nrc.firewall-iptables v$FWVER done.\n"
```

Via my VPN provider I have two ports forwarded so I can access various services on my Ubuntu Server via the VPN connection. When I don't have IP forwarding and Masquerading enabled (via the script in that article) it all works as expected but as soon as I use that script the forwarded ports do not work.

I've obviously missed something and do not know enough about iptables to figure out how I can still forward traffic from p4p1 to tun0 and still allow external access via the forwarded ports.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - if you'd be willing to provide an explanation of the solution you provide I would love to understand whats going on further.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely occurring due to the following rule:

```
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

This is **only** accepting `RELATED` or `ESTABLISHED` connections passing into the `tun0` (external) interface and out of the `p4p1` (internal) interface, so when outside connections attempt to connect to your port-forwarded service, the connection is dropped because it is `NEW`. You must modify that rule to either exclude the conntrack module altogether, or include the `NEW` parameter.

Either of the two below rules should solve your issue:

```
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -j ACCEPT
```

---

```
-A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Hope this helps